# agsxmpp create user account programmatically

Tags: openfire, agsxmpp

I am using agsXMPP library and Openfire server. Works nice. But I can`t find, how can I create new user account (add new user to openfire database) from agsXMPP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **RegisterAccount** to true. The rest of the code is equal to the normal login code.

Alex